# use the kCFStringTransformMandarinLatin to translate chinese，find wrong

Tags: ios, swift

I use the `kCFStringTransformMandarinLatin` to transform Chinese word `沈`,  it translates `chen`, but it right translator is `shen`, who can tell me why !

```
let strName = "沈"
let strNameMutable: NSMutableString = NSMutableString(string: strName)
if CFStringTransform(strNameMutable,nil,kCFStringTransformMandarinLatin, false){
    if CFStringTransform(strNameMutable,nil,kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics, false){
        let topIndex: String = strNameMutable as String
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but my dictionary lists shěn for 沈, but also chén as "variant of 沉." As a note, Google Translate also translates it as chén. https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E6%B2%88 (not to say that native speakers are wrong of course :D just saying that several dictionaries seem to go along with Apple here.)

Comment: Thanks , it's right! I think I must search for dictionary. And I need learn more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because,in Chinese,it is “多音字”,it means a Chinese word may have more than one “拼音”

[image]

Just as **@Rob Napier** said.

Since I am Chinese,I think posting a screenshot will make it easier to understand

Comment: Thanks for the picture!

Comment: @leo Cisco Shanghai? Are you at CRDC (is that still the location? I helped set that facility up back in my Cisco InfoSec days.)

Comment: @RobNapier Yes,I joined Cisco CRDC last year.